# Configurar correctamente sizers

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxwidgets

Os comentaré brevemente el problema:

Me gustaría diseñar una GUI que consista en una ventana de un tamaño dado(pongamos 500x600 pixeles) y dentro de ella por orden descendente tendríamos dos filas una bajo la otra con una etiqueta y un cuadro de texto(donde introducir datos, pero eso esta cubierto), una caja de texto donde volcar información y bajo de este último elemento tres botones.

Llevo muy poco manejándome con los *Sizers* pero creo entender 'mas o menos' como funcionan...Sin embargo, no consigo redimensionar inicialmente la ventana y los botones se quedan desproporcionados. Os adjunto mi código a ver si sabéis echarme una mano:

```
import wx
class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #Iniciamos el frame
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        #creamos los sizers
        #-----------------------------------------------
        #para la seccion principal
        self.sizerB=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #para la seccion de los botones
        self.sizerButtons=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        #para la seccion de Mensaje y Comando
        self.sizerGrid=wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2,cols=2,vgap=5,hgap=5)
        #------------------------------------------------

        #creamos las etiquetas
        #------------------------------------------------
        self.Mensaje=wx.StaticText(self,wx.ID_ANY,"Mensaje")
        self.Comando=wx.StaticText(self,wx.ID_ANY,"Comando")
        #-------------------------------------------------

        #Cajas de texto
        #-------------------------------------------------
        self.CajaM=wx.TextCtrl(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.CajaC=wx.TextCtrl(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        #-------------------------------------------------

        #creamos los botones(x3)
        #-------------------------------------------------
        self.SendM=wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY,"Enviar Mensaje")
        self.SendC=wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Enviar Comando")
        self.Exit=wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY,"Salir")
        #--------------------------------------------------

        #Agregamos sizers(configurarlos despues)
        #--------------------------------------------------
        #agregaremos el flexigridsizer para las dos primeras cajas y etiquetas
        for obj in [self.Mensaje,self.CajaM,self.Comando,self.CajaC]:
            self.sizerGrid.Add(obj,1,wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL,2)
        self.sizerGrid.AddGrowableCol(1)

        #Ahora le toca a los botones
        for obj in [self.SendM,self.SendC,self.Exit]:
            self.sizerButtons.Add(obj,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
            self.SetInitialSize((600,500))

        #---------------------------------------------------

        #Configuramos los sizers
        #---------------------------------------------------
        self.sizerB.Add(self.sizerGrid,2,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,5)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.sizerButtons,2,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,5)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerB)
        #----------------------------------------------------

        self.Centre(True)
        self.Show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=wx.App()
    fr=GUI(None,-1,"Aplicacion",size=(300,200))
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hola Alex, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Cómo quieres que se vean o comporten exactamente los botones? Tamaño y posición inicial, comportamiento al redimencionar la ventana, etc. Un pequeño esquema puede ser de gran ayuda en estos casos.

Comment: Pues en lo referente a la posicion principal me gustaria que la ventana fuera de 500x600 pixeles, e inmediatamente de arriba a abajo se vieran una etiqueta seguida de su cuadro de tecto( priemro Mensaje y abajo Comando). Inmediatamente despues un cuadro de texto que ocupara la maor parte del espacio (pues se mostrara ahi información) y seguidamente los botones en una fila de 3. Espero haber sido lo mas conciso posible. Gracias por la bienvenida y por la ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Alex he creado una respuesta, mira a ver si es más u menos la idea que tienes en mente. Cualquier cosa solo comenta.

Comment: Debido a que me habeis pedido mas informacion del proyecto y junto con el desarrollo del mismo me han surgido algunas dudas, creare un nuevo post donde explicare mejor mi problema. Aqui os lo dejo y gracias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154963/problemas-varios-con-modulo-cliente-py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clave para hacer lo que deseas es usar el parámetro `proportion` de tus `BoxSizer` adecuadamente. Este parámetro indica si el *sizer* es estirable en la orientación principal  y qué parte del espacio disponible ocupa el ítem.

**Si la proporción es *0*, entonces se usará el tamaño mínimo para contener el item**; si es *1*, recibirá una parte del tamaño disponible (después de lo que quede de restar el espacio de los items de tamaño fijo); si se usa *2*, recibirá dos partes, etc. Por ejemplo, si tienes un `BoxSizer` horizontal con tres botones, si al primero le asignas 1, al segundo 2 y al tercero 3 lo que hace es dividir el espacio en seis partes, el primer botón tendrá un sexto del espacio horizontal disponible del *sizer*, el segundo será el doble de ancho que el primero y el tercero el triple.

En tu caso añades dos *sizers* a tu `BoxSizer` principal y en ambos casos especificar el parámetro `proportion` en 2. Esto implica que se quedan cada uno con la mitad del tamaño del *sizer* principal.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior y anidando *sizers* de forma adecuada podemos conseguir lo que deseas, una posibilidad es la siguente:

```
import wx



class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # Iniciamos el frame
        super(GUI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Creamos un panel principal
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # Creamos los sizers
        #-----------------------------------------------
        self.main_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.form_fgrid = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=2, vgap=5, hgap=5)
        self.info_hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.button_hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        #-----------------------------------------------

        # Creamos las etiquetas
        #------------------------------------------------
        self.mensaje = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Mensaje")
        self.comando = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Comando")
        #-------------------------------------------------

        # Creamos las cajas de texto
        #-------------------------------------------------
        self.caja_mensaje = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.caja_comando = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY)
        #-------------------------------------------------

        # Creamos la caja para mostrar la informacion
        #-------------------------------------------------
        self.informacion = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", wx.Point(-1, -1), wx.Size(-1, -1), wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        #-------------------------------------------------

        # Creamos los botones(x3)
        #-------------------------------------------------
        self.send_mensaje = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Enviar Mensaje", size=(0, 35))
        self.send_comando = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Enviar Comando", size=(0, 35))
        self.send_exit = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Salir", size=(0, 35))
        #--------------------------------------------------

        # Configuramos los sizers
        #-------------------------------------------------
        # Añadimos etiquetas y cajas de texto a su FlexGrid
        self.form_fgrid.AddMany([(self.mensaje, 1),
                                 (self.caja_mensaje, 1, wx.EXPAND),
                                 (self.comando, 1),
                                 (self.caja_comando, 1, wx.EXPAND)])
        self.form_fgrid.AddGrowableCol(1, 1)

        # Añadimos la caja de texto para mostrar la información a su HBox
        self.info_hbox.Add(self.informacion, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        # Añadimos los botones a su HBox
        self.button_hbox.AddMany([(self.send_mensaje, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT, 10),
                                  (self.send_comando, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT, 10),
                                  (self.send_exit, 1, wx.EXPAND)])

        # Añadimos todos los sizers al VBox principal
        self.main_vbox.Add(self.form_fgrid, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.main_vbox.Add(self.info_hbox, 1,  wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM, 10)
        self.main_vbox.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.panel), 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.main_vbox.Add(self.button_hbox, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        #-------------------------------------------------

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.main_vbox)
        self.Centre(True)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    GUI(None, -1, "Aplicacion", size=(500, 600))
    app.MainLoop()
```

Con esto obtenemos los siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ventana inicialmente tiene unas dimensiones de 500x600 pero puede ser redimensionada o maximizada sin problemas. Si redimensionamos la ventana tanto los botones como el formulario inicial se adaptan al ancho de la ventana pero el alto es fijo. El `TextCtrl` central en cambio ocupa todo el ancho y alto disponible siempre.

Comment: Queria agradecerte el haberle dedicado tu tiempo a mi duda. Precisamente esto era lo que buscaba, asi que me pondre a aprender lo mejor posible sobre las caractersticas de este modulo.

Comment: De nada @AlexGA93, para eso estamos aquí, para intentar aprender unos de otros ツ. Como eres nuevo por aquí te informo que puedes aceptar aquella respuesta que consideres que soluciona mejor tu problema para indicar de su utilidad a otros usuarios futuros que puedan presentar un problema similar. Para saber como funciona esto puedes mirarte [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/15089). Un saludo.

Comment: Me preguntaba si podrias resolver una duda que me ha surgido con el devenir de la resolucion del codigo. Seria posible volcar informacion en un cuadro de texto como puede ser la TextCtrl llammada "self.informacion" a la que has llamado en tu version del codigo? o es necesario usar otro elemento para volcar informacion en una estructura parecida? Ante dudas a mi pregunta estare encantado de explicarme. Gracias

Comment: Hola @AlexGA93, si puedes volcar texto en el TextCtrl sin problemas pero para darte una idea de como abordarlo hace falta algo de más información. Una de las cosas a tener siempre en cuenta en GUIs es que no se puede bloquear el mainloop de la App nunca. Si tu texto se genera con llamadas bloqueantes y tarda en generarse debe hacerse esta operación de forma concurrente (hilos, procesos, etc) para no  bloquear el proceso de la App y no congelar la interfaz. ¿Exactamente de donde procede la información que quieres volcar y cómo la generas? .

Comment: Para modificar el contenido del `TextCtrl` tienes los métodos `AppendText`, `WriteText`, `Remove`, `Replace`, `Clear`, etc (ver https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextEntry.html#method-summary-methods-summary ). Como es una pregunta que difiere de esta puede resultar más cómodo y apropiado  crear otra pregunta diferente planteando el problema y explicando lo que que comento antes. Si decides hacerlo recuerda agregar algo que hayas o un [mcve] intentado para evitar que pueda ser cerrada por demasiado amplia o falta de investigación.